# Flux not decrypting using SOPS

Tags: kubernetes, flux, mozilla-sops

I have configured Flux to use SOPS to decrypt. Here's a brief highlight of what I did. In the `gotk-sync.yaml` file I have added the `decryption` property.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: flux-system
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 10m0s
  path: ./clusters/my-cluster
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: flux-system
  decryption:
    provider: sops
    secretRef:
      name: my-private-key
```

The secret `my-private-key` is created correctly and has the private key.

I have pushed the file and the change has taken effect.

In my application repo I have a secret file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: mysqlcreds
type: Opaque
data: null
stringData:
    DB_USER: bugs
    DB_PASSWORD: bunny
```

I'm encrypting this file with SOPS and pushing it. Flux picks up the change and reconciles. But the `stringData` values remain encrypted. My application gets these values from the environment variable and they show up encrypted like this:

```
ENC[AES256_GCM,data:PdU1ex4H,iv:p5u11vsmHc/tBVGV2g9kTsMSFvQDiYNEwFVeEeMg/pY=,tag:/JTTNNRnYh076EPAd8c/LA==,type:str]
```

I can't figure out why Flux is not decrypting the data. How do I debug this? `flux logs` shows nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was enabling SOPS for the wrong Git repo. I had to do that for my application git repo's Kustomization.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: my-demo-webapp
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 5m0s
  path: ./flux-config
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: my-demo-webapp
  targetNamespace: default
  decryption:
    provider: sops
    secretRef:
      name: my-private-key
```

After that decryption worked fine.